# PHP If / Else statement going directly to the Else without waiting for form input

Tags: php, if-statement

Ok so I have a form with 1 input and a submit button. Now I am using an if/else statement to make three acceptable answers for that input. Yes, No, or anything else. This if/else is working the thing is the code is kicking out the else function as soon as the page is loaded. I would like there to be nothing there until the user inputs then it would show one of three answers.

```
Welcome to your Adventure! You awake to the sound of rats scurrying  around your dank, dark cell. It takes a minute for your eyes to adjust to your surroundings. In the corner of the room you see what looks like a rusty key.
<br/>
Do you want to pick up the key?<br/>


<?php

//These are the project's variables.

$text2 = 'You take the key and the crumby loaf of bread.<br/>';

$text3 = 'You decide to waste away in misery!<br/>';

$text4 = 'I didnt understand your answer. Please try again.<br/>';

$a = 'yes';

$b = 'no';


// If / Else operators.

if(isset($_POST['senddata'])) {

    $usertypes = $_POST['name'];

}

if ($usertypes == $a){

    echo ($text2);
}

elseif ($usertypes == $b){

    echo ($text3);
}

else {

    echo ($text4);
}

?>

<form action="phpgametest.php" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
         <input type="submit" name="senddata" /><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call the code only when the POST value is set. This way it will only execute the code when the form was submitted (aka `$_POST['senddata']` is set):

```
if(isset($_POST['senddata'])) {

    $usertypes = $_POST['name'];

    if ($usertypes == $a){

        echo ($text2);
    }

    elseif ($usertypes == $b){

        echo ($text3);
    }

    else {
        echo ($text4);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3680300 Look at the close bracket `}`. Yours closes first, then you run the `if-elseif-else`, which means that it will run whether the form was submitted or not. You only want it to run when you send the data.

Comment: @user3680300 No take a look at your code! The first if statement is closed before the second

Comment: Ok. I actually had the whole thing encapsulated in the first bracket and it wasn't working...but then I put it over into a new tab and it worked. Refreshing the page after the code change didn't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks all for the help.

Comment: @user3680300 The page was probably just in cache and was loading the older page. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the validation in the first `if` statement like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['senddata'])) {

    $usertypes = $_POST['name'];


    if ($usertypes == $a) {
        echo ($text2);

    } elseif ($usertypes == $b) {
        echo ($text3);

    }  else {
        echo ($text4);
    }

}
```

Comment: You had the same idea (I was just a few seconds faster)...Hehehe.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The faster and correct one wins :D

Answer (score 0):

When you load your page the browser is making a GET request, when you submit your form the browser is making a POST request. You can check what request is made using:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  // Your form was submitted
}
```

Put this around your form processing code in order to keep it from being executed on GET request.